# Simple sort of each column in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I use VBA occasionally and I'm getting trapped in the syntax around ranges. I want to take an array as selected on the active sheet and sort each column one at a time returning an array of ordered columns. It seems simple with a `for` loop, however, I keep getting errors which I think relate to the scope.

```
Public Sub Sortrange() 'sorts each column in a range individually low to high
    Dim Rng, Sortcol As Range
  
        HH = Selection.Rows.Count
        Set Rng = Selection
        Srow = Rng(1).Row
        SCol = Rng(1).Column
        With Rng
          For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
            A = Srow
            B = SCol + i - 1
            Sortcol = Range(Cells(A, B), Cells(HH, B))
            Sortcol.Sort key1:=Range(Cells(A, B))
         Next
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Sortrange() 'sorts each column in a range individually low to high
    Dim Rng, Sortcol As Range
    Dim Srow As Integer, Scol As Integer
    Dim A, B, i As Integer
    
    Set Rng = Selection
    Dim selRows As Long: selRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    Dim selCols As Long: selCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    
    Srow = Rng(1).Row
    Scol = Rng(1).Column
    With Rng
      For i = 1 To selCols
        A = Srow
        B = Scol + i - 1
        Set Sortcol = Range(Cells(A, B), Cells(selRows + 1, B))
        
        ' Sort Column
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Sortcol _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With ActiveSheet.Sort
            .SetRange Sortcol
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
     Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I also did find that I can copy the array to the clipboard, have python read it from there, sort the array with one single statement and write it back to the clipboard. Yet its great to have this to add to my macros. I dont quite understand why the line with "Add2" is needed but never mind. Thanks again

Comment: The Sort part was done by recording a macro and then I replaced the range part with ``Sortcol``.